# I deployed a contract on remix, but none of the constructor variables are viewable

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, contract-deployment, constructor

I inherited the ERC-20 standard contract, but when I compile and deploy, none of the constructor variables are viewable. This problem persists even when I change "private" to "public".

[image]

As you can see on the left hand side, whenever I call the totalSupply or symbol or name functions, they don't return anything. Why is this?

Comment: Hi en! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Can you include the contract source as text! It will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Hi thanks! The problem was I had the wrong contract selected from the dropdown menu!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the initial problem is you've selected the wrong contract from the dropdown in the left pane:

[image: problem]

The names differ from the contract you have displayed.

[image: name]

Comment: LOL I feel dumb. That fixed it; thank you!

Comment: Hey @en it happens!  Please accept if resolved :)